# VueJS TailwindCSS paddings aren't responsive

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

In the first line of my code, I am expecting to have padding x-3 on mobile and padding x-32 on web version.
Everything works great on mobile but when I switch back to web version the padding x is still 3 not 32.

```
<div class="px-3 md:px-32 md:py-16">
        <div class="pb-16">
          <img src="../assets/line.svg" alt="" class="pb-2" />
          <p class="text-4xl text-left bt-medium pb-3">Example</p>
          <p class="text-4xl text-left bt-book">
            ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex md:flex-row flex-col items-center justify-between"> 
          <div class="px-3 flex flex-col items-center pb-8 md:pb-0">
            <div
              class="border-1 border-border-gray rounded-xl md:shadow-2xl w-full md:w-96 h-72 border-1 px-8 pt-8 relative pb-24"
            >
              <img class="w-12 h-12 mb-6" src="../assets/Example.png" />

              <p class="text-left bt-smalltitle font-bold pb-3.5">
                ExampleExampleExample
              </p>
              <p class="text-left bt-smalltext">
                ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
              </p>
            </div>
            <div
              class="bg-custom-gray hover:bg-custom-blue duration-300 h-9 w-11 relative rounded-xl -mt-6"
            >
              <button class="z-50">
                <img src="../assets/Arrow.svg" alt="" class="px-2 py-1.5" />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  content: [],
  variants: {
    display: ["responsive"],
    textColor: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "custom-blue": "#0096FF",
      },
      animation: ["group-hover"],
    },
  },
  variants: {
    textColor: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
    backgroundColor: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
    display: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
  
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: Working totally as expected here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/oCC9MfWkEN?size=652x720 You don't need to mess-up with any variants configuration. Also, in your code snippet you have `variants` twice.

Comment: @kissu can you please tell me how my tailwind.config.js file should look like? I removed variants but nothing changed.
Here is my current tailwind.config.js for testing:
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: Checked my previous comment? Everything works well there. No more needed in variants. Official source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#remove-variant-configuration

Comment: You can always reproduce the issue in the Tailwind's playground to show us why you do think that it's not working.

Comment: Yes @kissu , I checked and I understood that the problem is not on tailwind.config.js side. I'm trying to understand what other than that can cause the problem?

Comment: It works totally find in Tailwind's playground

Comment: Try to reproduce it somehow by looking at your code/devtools so. Can't help more here.